# C++ AMP Constructors

Tags: c++, parallel-processing, gpu, c++-amp

Do constructors for a struct that will be used in amp code need to have restrict(amp) included?  Ex:

```
struct Foo
{
  inline Foo(void)
  {
  }
  float a;
};
```

Or should it be like...

```
struct Foo
{
  inline Foo(void) restrict(amp)
  {
  }
  float a;
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. If you want to construct those objects within an AMP kernel. In the example below `stuff` instances are created on within the `amp` restricted `parallel_for_each`. The constructor needs to be marked as `restrict(amp)` in order to compile correctly.

```
class stuff
{
public:
    int a;

    stuff(int v) restrict(amp, cpu) 
        : a(v) { }
};

class test_case
{
public:
    test_case() { }

    void test_amp()
    {
        concurrency::array_view<stuff, 1> data(100);

        concurrency::parallel_for_each(data.extent,
            [data](concurrency::index<1> idx) restrict(amp)
        {
            data[idx] = stuff(s.a * s.a);
        });
        data.synchronize();
    };
};
```

I also wrote this up as a blog post, [Using C++ Classes with C++ AMP](http://www.ademiller.com/blogs/tech/2014/01/using-c-classes-with-c-amp/).